# Pass command-line arguments to grep as search patterns and print lines which match them all

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I'm learning about `grep` commands.
I want to make a program that when a user enters more than one word, outputs a line containing the word in the data file.
So I connected the words that the user typed with '|' and put them in the `grep` command to create the program I intended.
But this is OR operation. I want to make AND operation.

So I learned how to use AND operation with `grep` commands as follows.

```
cat <file> | grep 'pattern1' | grep 'pattern2' | grep 'pattern3'
```

But I don't know how to put the user input in the 'pattern1', 'pattern2', 'pattern3' position. Because the number of words the user inputs is not determined.
As user input increases, `grep` must be executed using more and more pipes, but I don't know how to build this part.

The user input is as follows:

```
$ [the name of my program] 'pattern1' 'pattern2' 'pattern3' ...
```

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggesting to use `awk` pattern logic:

```
 awk '/RegExp-pattern-1/ && /RegExp-pattern-2/ && /RegExp-pattern-3/ 1' input.txt
```

The advantages: you can play with logic operators `&&` `||` on RegExp patterns. And your are scanning the whole file once.

The disadvantages: must provide files list (can't traverse sub directories), and limited RegExp syntax compared to `grep -E` or `grep -P`

Comment: Of course, but the challenge is to get those patterns into Awk without hard-coding them in a new script file.

Comment: It was really helpful! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

With `grep -f` you can grep multiple items, when each of them is on a line in a file.

With `<(command)` you can let Bash think that the result of `command` is a file.

With `printf "%s\n"` and a list of arguments, each argument is printed on a new line.

Together:

```
grep -f <(printf "%s\n" "$@") datafile
```

Comment: The process substitution is a Bash feature, but the wording there is odd. It's actually Bash which makes the result look like a file to `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, what you are asking could be done with a loop with output to a temporary file.

```
file=inputfile
temp=$(mktemp -d -t multigrep.XXXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -rf "$temp"' ERR EXIT
for regex in "$@"; do
    grep "$regex" "$file" >"$temp"/output
    mv "$temp"/output "$temp"/input
    file="$temp"/input
done
cat "$temp"/input
```

However, a better solution is probably to arrange for Awk to check for all the patterns in one go, and avoid reading the same lines over and over again.

Passing the arguments to Awk with quoting intact is not entirely trivial. Here, we simply pass them as command-line arguments and process those into an array within the Awk script itself.

```
awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1; i<ARGC; ++i) a[i]=ARGV[i];
        ARGV[1]="-"; ARGC=1 }
{ for(n=1; n<=i; ++n) if ($0 !~ a[n]) next; }1' "$@" <file
```

In brief, in the `BEGIN` block, we copy the command-line arguments from `ARGV` to `a`, then replace `ARGV` and `ARGC` to pass Awk a new array of (apparent) command-line arguments which consists of just `-` which means to read standard input.  Then, we simply iterate over `a` and skip to the next line if the current input line from standard input does not match. Any remaining lines have matched all the patterns we passed in, and are thus printed.

Comment: When you want `awk`, not `grep -f`, you can avoud ARGC tricks with `awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next} i==0 && NR>FNR {i=NR-1} {for(n=1; n<=i; ++n) if ($0 ~ a[n]) print }'  <(printf "%s\n" $*) file`. I would prefer to change i and n: `awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next} n==0 && NR>FNR {n=NR-1} {for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) if ($0 ~ a[i]) print }'  <(printf "%s\n" $*) file`